# How to show prime symbol in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to show SS' in the xtics of a graph. I don't know how I can have the prime symbol in gnuplot like it is shown on latex like this : SS$'$?

ps: This is the terminal setting I have:

```
    set terminal postscript eps size 8.5cm, 7cm dashed 
    dashlength 3.0 enhanced color font 'Helvetica,10'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `epslatex` terminal instead, and just use latex syntax:

```
set terminal epslatex color dashed standalone size 8.5cm,7cm
set output "out.tex"
set label "This is a prime symbol: $'$" at graph 0.5,0.5 center
plot sin(x)
```

[image]

Comment: I have to save the output in eps format for its the format which is accepted. Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: You can export to eps after running latex: dvi > ps > eps. I am not familiar with the tools that do this but I do know they exist. Another option is that you use the `postscript eps` terminal and encapsulate a font which has the symbols you need, type `help set term postcript` for help. Personally, I find the first option more convenient. Finally, if it's for publication, most journals will accept pdf figures, which is what I use, even though the give you guidelines that say "eps only".